How to create a column for TableView in JavaFX with leading ellipsis?
I have a column with paths where all paths belong to one root folder. When paths do not fit in the column (they can be rather long and column width is limited) I want to show user only the end of the path with leading ellipsis. For example:
..someverylongdirectoryname/file.txt
..omeverylongdirectoryname/file2.txt

I tried this code, but it didn't work.
public class JavaFxTest extends Application {


    public static class FilePath {
        private final String path;

        public FilePath(String path) {
            this.path = path;
        }

        public String getPath() {
            return path;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TableView<FilePath> tableView = new TableView<>();

        TableColumn<FilePath, String> pathColumn = new TableColumn<>("Path");
        pathColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("path"));
        pathColumn.setPrefWidth(200);

        pathColumn.setCellFactory(column -> new javafx.scene.control.TableCell<>() {
            private final Text text = new Text();

            @Override
            protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (empty || item == null) {
                    setGraphic(null);
                } else {
                    text.setText(item);
                    text.setStyle("-fx-text-alignment: right;");
                    setGraphic(text);
                }
            }
        });

        tableView.getColumns().add(pathColumn);
        tableView.getItems().addAll(
            new FilePath("/usr/local/bin/someverylongdirectoryname/file.txt"),
            new FilePath("/usr/local/bin/someverylongdirectoryname/file2.txt")
        );

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(tableView, 300, 200));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

Could anyone say how to do it?

See also ElidedTableViewSample.

It looks like you are looking to have the text overrun ellipsis at the beginning of the label, instead of the end. Just use the fact that the Cell is a Labeled and set the overrun style:
        pathColumn.setCellFactory(column -> new javafx.scene.control.TableCell<>() {

            {
                setTextOverrun(OverrunStyle.LEADING_ELLIPSIS);
            }
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                setText(item);
            }
        });

Of course, you can also just manually replace the root folder if you prefer:
        String commonPath = "/usr/local/bin/someverylongdirectoryname";

        pathColumn.setCellFactory(column -> new javafx.scene.control.TableCell<>() {


            @Override
            protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (empty || item == null) {
                    setText(null);
                } else {
                    setText(item.replace(commonPath, "..."));
                }
            }
        });

